# Adding items to IEnumerable<T> when creating new class object

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class that I am populating with a view to serializing into `JSON`

My class has strings and one `IEnumerable` of a second class (`Icons`)

```
public class ManifestModel
    {
        public string ShortName { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Icon> Icons { get; set; }

        public string BackgroundColour { get; set; }

        public string ThemeColour { get; set; }

        public class Icon
        {
            public string Src { get; set; }

            public string Type { get; set; }

            public string Sizes { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

When creating an instance of ManifestModel, it is easy enough to populate the string properties, but how do I add my two icon variables (`icon192` and `icon512`)?

```
 var icon192 = new ManifestModel.Icon
            {
                Src = "192",
                Type = "images/png",
                Sizes = "192x192"
            };

 var icon512 = new ManifestModel.Icon
            {
                Src = "512",
                Type = "images/png",
                Sizes = "512x512"
            };

            var manifestModel = new ManifestModel
            {
                ShortName = siteRoot.GetValue<string>("siteTitle"),
                Name = siteRoot.GetValue<string>("siteName"),
                //how to add two Icon objects here
            };
```

I have tried

Comment: It is a bad idea to expose a `IEnumerable<>` with a get/set. Normally you should use a `IReadOnlyCollection<>` or a `IReadOnlyList<>` (the solution of Rafal/Thierry can still be used) This because you shouldn't ever enumerate twice a `IEnumerable<>`, but by putting it in a `get`/`set` it isn't clear how many times it will be enumerated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create an array and assign to Icons property.

```
var manifestModel = new ManifestModel
{    
    Icons  = new[] { icon192, icon512 },
    //...
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `Icons` is an `IEnumerable`, you can create a list

```
var manifestModel = new ManifestModel
        {
            Icons = new List<ManifestModel.Icon>() { icon192, icon512 },    
            //do something
```

Comment: You should create a `List<>` when you want to expand it, not for fixed-size containers. Better to use arrays. And `new List<ManifestModel.Icon> { ... }`. No auto-discovery of `List<>` types in C#.

Comment: @xanatos thanks for your comment. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is uncommon to use a read/write property to maintain a list of items in an object. What you generally want is a solution, where you can just write:

```
foreach (Icon icon in model.Icons) {
    //Do something
}
```

With a read/write property, `Icons` can be `null` and the result will be a `NullReferenceException`.

What is even worse is that you will add the potential for subtle bugs. When you start iterating over `Icons` and you set the value during the iteration, you might expect that you are continuing to iterate over the new list. This is not the case though, you're still iterating over the previous value. Usually in these cases the original iteration should fail with an `InvalidOperationException` upon continuation.

To avoid this problem, use a collection that is derived from `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>` and expose it as a property:

```
public class IconCollection : Collection<Icon> {
    //Customize here
}

public class ManifestModel
{
    //
    public IconCollection Icons { get; } = new IconCollection();
    //...
}
```

When you want to add items you go:

```
model.Icons.Add(icon);
```

This will avoid the problems described above.